# How can I make a single link in a top navigation a different backgound color in wordpress?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to make a single link in a WordPress top navigation menu that has a different background color but running into some issues.

What I have works on most of my pages but others not (as seen below). I assigned a CSS class (.contact-us-menu) to the individual menu item in the menu builder in WordPress, but I can seem to figure out how to get it to work across all the pages.

[image: Wrong] 

Wrong. (https://www.csolsinc.com/insights/)

[image: Correct] 

Correct. (https://www.csolsinc.com/insights/webinars/)

This is the custom CSS I added with the "Wordpress Add Custom CSS" plugin.

```css
li.contact-us-menu {
background-color:#f47e00!important;
height:50px!important;
border-radius:50px!important;
padding-right:15px;
color:#ffffff!important;
font-weight:bold!important;
vertical-align:middle;
}

li.contact-us-menu a {
color:#ffffff!important;
}
```

Any advice?

Answer (score -1):

I looked through both of your site pages to look for the differences and I am seeing this line affecting the 'wrong' links:

```
#top-menu .menu-item .dropdown-toggle {
    position: relative;
    top: 11px !important;
```

For a fix, with your I would either change the top to -1px as in your 'correct' 
or try to add:

```
li.contact-us-menu {
line-height: 50px;
}
```

to your css.